# GetPrivateProfileInt- reading only the default values

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, configuration, win32-process

I am trying to read a .init config file in c++ having the content.

> [Ipaddress]
>
> Ipaddress=169.254.115.22
>
> [ScanConfiguration]
>
> Scanfrequency=2500
>
> ScanResolution=2500
>
> StartAngle=700000
>
> StopAngle=1100000

Till Now, I have used this code for reading the data. My project is of Unicode character set and hence used L before the string values.

```
 int iScanFreq =GetPrivateProfileInt(L"ScanConfiguration",L"Scanfrequency", 2500, L"filename.ini");
  int iScanRes =GetPrivateProfileInt(L"ScanConfiguration",L"ScanResolution", 2500, L"filename.ini");
  int iStartAngle =GetPrivateProfileInt(L"ScanConfiguration",L"StartAngle", -450000, L"filename.ini");
  int iStopAngle =GetPrivateProfileInt(L"ScanConfiguration",L"StopAngle", 2250000, L"filename.ini");
```

But I am getting only the default values in the variables not the correct values from the file. I have not done anything with the registry yet. Is there anything I have to do in registry for getting the correct value..

Any suggestions will be helpful
Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One idea comes to mind: GetPrivateProfileString and friends have a bit of a quirk with how they find the INI file. Unless you specify a path to the INI file (even something as simple as `.\filename.ini`), they assume the file is located in the Windows directory. This is almost certainly not what you want, and will probably lead to not finding the file, and thus to default values.

Also, don't expect full Unicode support from those functions. [They're just Unicode wrappers around ANSI text.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/11/26/6523907.aspx)

Comment: Double-check your INI file in that case. It may have a BOM (byte order mark) or something similar which could confuse the parser.

Comment: I checked the error using GetLastError() and is returning 2 which means that the it cannot find the specified path.