# GetPrivateProfileInt always return default value

Tags: c++, default, ini

I am using Visual Studio 2019 on a Windows x64 PC and I have the simple code listed below:

The "magazzini.ini" file is like this:

```
[Delicarta]
A=55
B=80
```

The output values returned by GetPrivateProfileInt are always the default values 0 and not the values that I wrote in the file.
How can I solve this problem? I have to put the file in a special directory?

I tried to change the file name as ".\magazzini.ini", and also writing the complete path (C:.. ) but i didn't solve the problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int A, B;

    // leggo i parametri dal file magazzini.ini
    A = GetPrivateProfileInt(L"Delicarta", L"A", 0, L"magazzini.ini");
    B = GetPrivateProfileInt(L"Delicarta", L"B", 0, L"magazzini.ini");

    cout << "Il valore del parametro A e' " << A << "\n";
    cout << "Il valore del parametro B e' " << B << "\n";

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GetPrivateProfileInt- reading only the default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239576/getprivateprofileint-reading-only-the-default-values)

Comment: You need to specify the path as ".\\magazine.ini"

Comment: You showed what is in the ini file, but never mentioned *where* it is. And we cannot say your "complete path" attempt was valid because you never showed it (the path) and for all we know you didn't escape the separators correctly. When run from the integrated debugger  the default working directory is the folder containing the *project* file (the .vcprojx file) of your project. Putting the file there, and using `".\\magazzini.ini"` as the file name *should* work.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [`GetPrivateProfileInt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprivateprofileint) documentation:

> `lpFileName`
>
> The name of the initialization file. **If this parameter does not contain a full path to the file, the system searches for the file in the Windows directory.**

So, you MUST provide a full absolute path to the INI file. `L"magazzini.ini"` and `L".\\magazzini.ini"` will not work the way you expect.

If the INI file is in the same folder as your executable, use `GetModuleFileName()` to retrieve the full path to your executable, and then replace the filename portion as needed, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int A, B;

    WCHAR iniFilename[MAX_PATH] = {};
    GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, iniFilename, MAX_PATH);
    PathRemoveFileSpecW(iniFileName);
    PathCombineW(iniFilename, iniFilename, L"magazzini.ini");

    // leggo i parametri dal file magazzini.ini
    A = GetPrivateProfileInt(L"Delicarta", L"A", 0, iniFilename);
    B = GetPrivateProfileInt(L"Delicarta", L"B", 0, iniFilename);

    cout << "Il valore del parametro A e' " << A << "\n";
    cout << "Il valore del parametro B e' " << B << "\n";

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried to put the full path L"C:\\Users\\User\\source\\repos\\Posizione_ancore_2.0.cpp\\Posizione_ancore_2.0\\magazzini.ini" but still have the same problem. I also tried to put the file in the Windows directory (C:\\Windows) and still obltained A=0 and B=0... :(

Comment: @SimoneSciarretta the only way that can happen is if the API can't find the INI file. Use [SysInternals Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see exactly where it is looking for the file and why it can't find it